# binding muliple data from sql to label by choosing item in combobox

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, sql-server-2008

how i bind multiple data from sql to label if i choose an item in combo box that is from sql this is my code:

```
    Private Sub cmboCourse_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmboCourse.SelectedIndexChanged

    If cmboCourse.Text = "ADVANCED COMPUTER TECHNICIAN" Then
        callMe()
    ElseIf cmboCourse.Text = "AUTOELECTRICITY" Then
        callMe()
    ElseIf cmboCourse.Text = "AUTOMOTIVE" Then
        callMe()
    End If

End Sub


Private Sub callMe()

Dim str As String = ("Data Source=PC1; User ID=sa; Password=pwd;Databasfriend")
Dim con As New SqlConnection(str)
Dim str1 As String = "SELECT * FROM tbl_course"
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(str1, con)
Dim dataset1 As New DataSet()
da.Fill(dataset1, "course")
lbl.DataBindings.Add("text", dataset1, "course.Course_Code")

end sub
```

and this is my table

```
 Course_Code      Course
 ACT              ADVANCED COMPUTER TECHNICIAN
 AE               AUTOELECTRICITY
 AM               AUTOMOTIVE
```

it binds only one data, i want to bind many data in a particular column example i choose a course AUTOMOTIVE in combo box how does course_code of AUTOMOTIVE binds to label and if i choose AUTOELECTRICITY how does course_code of AUTOELECTRICITY binds to the same label

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested, let me know if it doesn't work.

```
Private Sub cmboCourse_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmboCourse.SelectedIndexChanged
    callMe(cmboCourse.Text)
End Sub


Private Sub callMe(ByVal course as String)

    Dim str As String = ("Data Source=PC1; User ID=sa; Password=pwd;Databasfriend")
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(str)
    Dim str1 As String = "SELECT * FROM tbl_course WHERE [Course]='" & course & "'"
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(str1, con)
    Dim dataset1 As New DataSet()
    da.Fill(dataset1, "tbl_course")
    'lbl.DataBindings.Add("text", dataset1, "course.Course_Code")
    If dataset1.Tables("tbl_course").Rows.Count > 0 Then
        lbl.Text = dataset1.Tables("tbl_course").Rows(0)("Course_Code")
    Else
        MsgBox "Course [" & course & "] not found"
    End If

End Sub
```

Please note that in your code, `da.Fill(dataset1, "course")` you specify the table to be 'course', while the select statement selects from 'tbl_course' table. I am assuming the latter is correct name.

### Edit 1:

Bug fix

### Edit 2:

Debugging

Comment: fixed it with `lbl.Text = dataset1.Tables("tbl_course").Rows(0)("Course_Code")`

Comment: callMe(cmboCourse.Text) - too many arguements to private sub callme() and course after [Course]='"&  - not declare it may be inaccessible due to its protection level thats all sir

Comment: You didnt change the callMe definition: `Private Sub callMe(ByVal course as String)`

Comment: sir i run the program then have error on this lbl.Text = dataset1.Tables("tbl_course").Rows(0)("Course_Code") -- object reference no set to an instance of an object

Comment: What is it pointing to? Do you actually have a label called `lbl`? Or maybe you don't have any records returning. Put the statement inside `If dataset1.tables("tbl_course").Rows.Count > 0`

Comment: I edited my main post to debug the issue. I believe your SQL does not return a course. Try that please and let me know the results.

Comment: Course [System.Data.DataRowView] not found

Answer (score 0):

sc.Open()
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter()

```
    Dim dataset1 As New DataSet()
    Dim sql As New SqlCommand("Select * from book where Title='" + cmbtit.Text + "'", sc)

    da.SelectCommand = sql
    da.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    da.Fill(dataset1, "book")

    If dataset1.Tables("book").Rows.Count > 0 Then
        txtauthor.Text = dataset1.Tables("book").Rows(0)("Author")
    Else
        MsgBox("Author [" & cmbtit.Text & "] not found")
    End If
    sc.Close()

End Sub
```